# PHPMailer SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server i am hosting this php in easyphp The extension=php_openssl.dll is already uncommended

Tags: phpmailer

```
     <?php
     $mailto=$_POST['mail_to'];

$mailsub=$_POST['mail_sub'];

  $mailtext=$_POST['mail_text'];
     require("PHPMailer_5.2.4/PHPMailer_5.2.4/class.phpmailer.php");
       require("PHPMailer_5.2.4/PHPMailer_5.2.4/class.smtp.php");


                    $mail=new PHPMailer(false);
                       $mail->IsSmtp();
               $mail->SMTPDebug=1;
                   $mail->SMTPAuth=true;
              $mail->SMTPSecure="ssl";//smtp protocol
                     $mail->Host="smtp.gmail.com";
                   $mail->port=587;//ssl port number
          $mail->IsHTML(true);
           $mail->Username="myuser@gmail.com";
               $mail->Password="mypassword";
                 $mail->SetFrom("myuser@gmail.com");
                          $mail->Subject=$mailsub;
              $mail->Body=$mailtext;
                    $mail->AddAddress($mailto);
                  if(!$mail->Send()){
                   echo "mail is not sent";
                                   }
            else{
                echo "mail sent sucess fully";
            }


                      ?>
```

i also changed to tls with port number 587 but it also showing the error i hosting this php in easy php

Comment: Search before you post, read the docs, show what your error is. You're also using an ancient, buggy and vulnerable version of PHPMailer. [Upgrade now](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: I have updated to latest version but now it showing the error like phpmailer class not found

Comment: Read the readme that tells you how to load PHPMailer, and base your code on an up-to-date example.

Comment: please tell the steps how to install phpmailer

Comment: and now i am using 5.2 stable version but it showing the following error2018-03-15 12:47:43 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
mail is not sent

Comment: Right, so read the guide and do the tests it describes so you can diagnose what's wrong with your server.